# ASP.NET Swagger WebApi with multiple apps

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger

We use multiple web apps on same IIS.

It's seems like

1) http://serverName:8080

2) http://serverName:8080/Products

3) http://serverName:8080/PersonalData

Path to Swagger:
http://serverName:8080/swagger/

**swagger.json** generates only from first service.

How to generate **swagger.json** from **all** services and place it on **first**?

Comment: It is generated for all however, you have to change the URL for the json file in the swagger UI page to include the relative path. ex: /prdocuts or PersonalData